# Android Wear can't connect my device via bluetooth

Tags: wear-os, nexus-4, moto-360

I enabled debugging over bluetooth on my Moto 360
and enabled Android Wear app on my Nexus4.

Status displays  `target : disconnected`

Forwarding the port from my computer shows the status host will be changed to connected, but the target status remains disconnected.

I toggled debug via the bluetooth switch which had no effect.
My phone is a Nexus 4. Is there a problem with my phone or the Moto 360?

Comment: i tried connect with sony z1 , it sussced ,so maybe its a bug with nexus4

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  The Target stays `disconnected` no matter what I try.

Comment: Same here. It seems to be related to the fact I previously associated my handheld with an emulator. Somehow now the companion app doesn't seem to handle that properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

I tried it on a Sony z1.
It succeeded without any problems.

So, maybe it's not supported perfectly in Nexus 4.

If you have the same problem, I suggest using another device.

Answer (score 7):

I eventually managed to get it working. The issue seems to be related to having paired your device with an emulator first. Take a look at this post to see how I fixed it: http://melix.github.io/blog/2014/10/android-moto360.html

Comment: Ahh yeah this worked for me, the only thing I might add is that only step 2 was required (clear cache, clear data). However, I also had to go into the Android Wear companion app and forget the Emulator device.

Answer (score 3):

1. open the applications settings, search for the Android Wear application, then force stop it
2. clear its data and cache
3. Search for Google Play Services

   1. Click on Manage space. Delete all data.
4. reboot your phone
5. reset your Moto 360
6. Pair watch with phone
7. Following the instructions from android.com https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/apps/bt-debugging.html to setup debugging and it should work now.

Comment: i tried reset the nexus 4 and using the factory image to update Android 5.0.1 with clear all data. but it again.
i use nexus 6 now, it works!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed without factory reset with these steps

-Force stop android wear application and clear cache

-Disconnect emulator on android wear app

-Forget emulator on android wear app

-Connect your real device via bluetooth

-Open debugging over bluetooth

Make sure that debugging options are also active in android wear device

Answer (score -2):

Run this commands in command window:

```
adb forward tcp:4444 localabstract:/adb-hub
adb connect localhost:4444
```

Comment: thanks a lot ,but i means target is disconnect . not host status disconnect.adb forward is using adb connect to the host